# Django model relations best practice

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on Django web-site, where users can add draft laws to "watch list" to be notified on draft status change. At the moment I have two models connected by many to many relation:

```
class DraftLaw(models.Model):
    '''some atributes and methods'''

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    '''some atributes and methods'''
```

Though, I want to allow users to add comments, visible only to them, to particular drafts, they are watching. My only idea is to add another class CommentToDraft, which will be related by foreign key to both DraftLaw and UserProfile classes and to access it by filters, although it seems, that it is bad practice in terms of efficiency.
What is the best practice to create such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is OK. If you want something more flexible, I suggest you use [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). I always use them for comments and attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Your Idea is pretty much ok, but if You care about efficiency, consider to customize authentication. I mean delete `models.OneToOne` and use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/) solution.

access to 'UserProfile' can cost some additional queries. With `AbstractBaseUser` You can avoid this.

Set up this solution is very simple :)